# In a certain state $55$ vote for Donald. $3$ voters are selected at random find the probability that...

Tags: probability

In a certain state $55$ vote for Donald. $3$ voters are selected at random find the probability that

A) all 3 voted for donald

B) exactly 2 will vote for donald

C) all 3 will not vote for donald

This makes me confuse because I don't have the number of voters. I don't know how to find the number of voters so i have for A) P(All voted)=$\frac{3C3}{xC3}$ where C stands for combination. If you may please tell the topic that I need to work on to and answer it step by step. I was taught combinations only but I think its not applicable here?

The question does not have a total number of voters just the percentage, can baye's theorem be applied here?

Comment: Total number of voters should be their

Comment: If that _is_ supposed to read 55 _percent_, then you just have a binomial probabllity distribution to deal with.  You then don't know to know the number of people in the voter "population".

Comment: Gah, that should say "don't _need_ to know" -- time to get some shut-eye...

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the 55 is just the percentage. So for any randomly chosen voter, $P(d) = \frac{55}{100} = \frac{11}{20}$, where $d$ denotes the event that the voter voted for Donald.

So we choose $n=3$ voters with "success probability" $p = \frac{11}{20}$.

The chance that all have "success" is just $p \times p \times p$ by independence of the voters chosen. So the total probability all three voted for Donald is $p^3$.

The chance that we have three non-Donald-voters is similarly $(1-p)^3$.

Exactly two voters: the non-Donald-voter can be the first, second or third voter we pick. So we get $3$ times $p^2$ (two Donald voters) times $(1-p)$ (the non-Donald-voter), in one formula $3p^2(1-p)$.